# DASK Memory Per Worker Guide

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I'm currently working on refactoring some legacy analytics into Python/DASK to show the efficacy of this as a solution going forward.

I'm trying to set up a demo scenario and am having problems with memory and would like some advice.

My scenario; I have my data split into 52 gzip compressed parquet files on S3, each one, uncompressed in memory is around 100MB, giving a total dataset size of ~5.5GB and exactly 100,000,000 rows.

My scheduler is on a T2.Medium (4GB/2vCPUs) as are my 4 workers.
Each worker is being run with 1 process, 1 thread and a memory limit of 4GB, I.e. `dask-worker MYADDRESS --nprocs 1 --nthreads=1 --memory-limit=4GB`.

Now, I'm pulling the parquet files and immediately repartitioning on a column in such a way that I end up with roughly 480 partitions each of ~11MB.

Then I'm using map_partitions to do the main body of work.
This works fine for small datasets, however for the 100 mil dataset, my workers keep crashing due to not having enough memory.
What am I doing wrong here?
For implementation specific info, the function i'm passing to map_partitions can sometimes need roughly 1GB, due to what is essentially a cross join on the partition dataframe.

Am I not understanding something to do with DASK's architecture? Between my scheduler and my 4 workers there is 20GB of memory to work with, yet this is proving to be not enough.
From what I've read from the DASK documentation is that, so long as each partition, and what you do with that partition, fits in the memory of the worker then you should be ok?

Is 4GB just not enough? Does it need way more to handle scheduler/inter process communication oerheads?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: few questions: how is `pandas` involved here? what bit-version of python are you running - 32bit has a 2GB limit.

Comment: @MattR, true, it has nothing to do with Pandas, I've removed the tag.
64bit, I'm running on an x86 Ubuntu18.04 Amazon community AMI

Comment: As much as I love this question, I don't think this is specifically the write. Maybe try in meta?

Comment: Sure, shall I delete this and move it there?

Answer (score 0):

See https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/best-practices.html#avoid-very-large-partitions

I'll copy the text here for convenience

Your chunks of data should be small enough so that many of them fit in a worker’s available memory at once. You often control this when you select partition size in Dask DataFrame or chunk size in Dask Array.

Dask will likely manipulate as many chunks in parallel on one machine as you have cores on that machine. So if you have 1 GB chunks and ten cores, then Dask is likely to use at least 10 GB of memory. Additionally, it’s common for Dask to have 2-3 times as many chunks available to work on so that it always has something to work on.

If you have a machine with 100 GB and 10 cores, then you might want to choose chunks in the 1GB range. You have space for ten chunks per core which gives Dask a healthy margin, without having tasks that are too small

Comment: I did read the docs before posting the question, I still don't understand why my setup isn't working.

Comment: I've since increased the number of rows to 200 million, but i've also added 2 extra workers and an extra 4GB to each worker and the scheduler. So, now, there are 6 workers with a combined memory of 48GB of RAM and i'm still getting the same issues. Something really doesn't seem right. The input dataframe is only ~8GB